# Use regular expressions to check for a special mailbox format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression,but it didn't meet my needs.I don't want capitalized English characters in my mailbox.In fact,there is only one wrong case(littlecxy@google.COM),I don't want uppercase English characters behind the decimal point.

The regular expression is shown below:

```
^[a-z0-9.$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. You might want to improve your question a little bit, by adding a list of your desired outputs against a list of inputs that contains strings *not* to be matched as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**\w** matches any uppercase and lowercase alphanumeric character plus underscore

instead of **\w** use **[a-z0-9_]**

```
^[a-z0-9.$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)*\.[a-z0-9_]+([-.][a-z0-9_]+)*$
```